# help with text alignment within table cells

Tags: tables, formatting, positioning, alignment, cell

im using tabularx and have my tables formated to the size i want but the text in each cell is alligned kinda weird - words are spilling over to a new line but I would rather the whole word go on a new line, not really sure how to change this, any help is appreciated:

```
\begin{table}[h]

\centering

\footnotesize

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X| X| X|| X| X |X|}      

\hline

\textbf{Criteria} & \textbf{Criteria Detail} & \textbf{Weight} & \textbf{Symphony AI Summit Service Management} & \textbf{InvGate Service Desk} & \textbf{Proactivanet} \\

\hline

Feature Suitability & IT Support Enablement/ Multichannel Engagement & 10 & 9.2 & 9 & 9.9 \\

\hline

Incident Management & Case Management & 5 & 4.6 & 4.6 & 4.8 \\

\hline

Change Management & Adaptive Change \& Release & 5 & 4.5 & 4.3 & 4.9 \\

\hline

Problem Management & case Managment/IT Support Enablement & 10 & 9.2 & 9.2 & 9.8 \\

\hline

Knowledge Management & IT Knowledge Management & 5 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.8 \\

\hline

Usability and User Experience & User Experience & 5 & 4.5 & 4.9 & 4.7 \\

\hline

Interface and Navigation & User Experience/ Overhead & 10 & 8.9 & 9.3 & 9.6 \\

\hline

User Training and Documentation & Quality of End-User Training/ Service Reporting and Resource Management & 10 & 9.2 & 8.9 & 9.7 \\

\hline

Integration and Compatibility & Integrated AI/Workflow Automation \& Integration/Ease of Deployment & 15 & 13.3 & 13 & 14.5 \\

\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you permit automatic linebreaking in columns 1, 2, and 4; disable full justification; align the numbers in the four data columns on their explicit or implicit decimal markers; not render the contents of the header row in bold; and, last but not least, get rid of all vertical lines and use far fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\newcommand\mcC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\small

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL T{2.0} *{3}{T{2.1}} @{}}      

\toprule

Criteria & Criteria Detail & {Weight} & 
\mcC{Symphony AI Summit Service Management} & 
{InvGate Service Desk} & {Proactivanet} \\

\midrule

Feature Suitability & IT Support Enablement\slash Multichannel Engagement & 10 & 9.2 & 9.0 & 9.9 \\

\addlinespace

Incident Management & Case Management & 5 & 4.6 & 4.6 & 4.8 \\

\addlinespace

Change Management & Adaptive Change \& Release & 5 & 4.5 & 4.3 & 4.9 \\

\addlinespace

Problem Management & Case Managment\slash IT Support Enablement & 10 & 9.2 & 9.2 & 9.8 \\

\addlinespace

Knowledge Management & IT Knowledge Management & 5 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.8 \\

\addlinespace

Usability and User Experience & User Experience & 5 & 4.5 & 4.9 & 4.7 \\

\addlinespace

Interface and Navigation & User Experience/ Overhead & 10 & 8.9 & 9.3 & 9.6 \\

\addlinespace

User Training and Documentation & Quality of End-User Training\slash Service Reporting and Resource Management & 10 & 9.2 & 8.9 & 9.7 \\

\addlinespace

Integration and Compatibility & Integrated AI/ Workflow Automation \& Integration\slash Ease of Deployment & 15 & 13.3 & 13.0 & 14.5 \\

\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! looks much better

Answer (score 0):

A `tabularray` variation of the nice @Mico answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitably
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{colsep  = 4pt,
             colspec = {@{}  X[1.5,l] X[2.5,l] 
                             X[0.9,c,si={table-format=2.0}] 
                             X[1.3,c,si={table-format=2.0}]
                        *{2}{X[0.9,c,si={table-format=2.1}]} 
                        @{}},
             cells   = {font=\small\linespread{0.84}\relax},
             row{1}  = {guard, m}
            }
    \toprule
Criteria 
    & Criteria Detail & Weight 
        & Symphony AI Summit Service Management
            & InvGate Service Desk
                    & Proacti\-vanet          \\
    \midrule
Feature Suitability 
    & IT Support Enablement\slash Multichannel Engagement   & 10 & 9.2 & 9.0 & 9.9  \\
Incident Management 
    & Case Management                                       & 5  & 4.6 & 4.6 & 4.8  \\
Change Management 
    & Adaptive Change \& Release                            & 5  & 4.5 & 4.3 & 4.9  \\
Problem Management 
    & Case Managment\slash IT Support Enablement            & 10 & 9.2 & 9.2 & 9.8  \\
Knowledge Management 
    & IT Knowledge Management                               & 5  & 4.5 & 4.5 & 4.8  \\
Usability and User Experience 
    & User Experience                                       & 5  & 4.5 & 4.9 & 4.7  \\
Interface and Navigation 
    & User Experience/ Overhead                             & 10 & 8.9 & 9.3 & 9.6  \\
User Training and Documentation 
    & Quality of End-User Training\slash Service Reporting and Resource Management 
                                                            & 10 & 9.2 & 8.9 & 9.7  \\
Integration and Compatibility 
    & Integrated AI/ Workflow Automation \& Integration\slash Ease of Deployment 
                                                            & 15 & 13.3 & 13.0 & 14.5 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]